# A concrete example of a non-pure-point measure

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

I am considering $P(\mathbb{R})$ the space of probability measures on the real line.  We can regard this as within the space of continuous linear functionals on the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity, and this topologizes via the weak* topology.  The collection $C$ of probability measures that place all its mass on $[0, \infty)$ is closed in $P(\mathbb{R})$ with this topology.  This $C$ seems to be "continuum" and it feels like not all probability measures on it (so yes I'm talking about probability measures on a space of probability measures) should be countable sums of point masses.

An explicit counterexample or recipe for generating counterexamples would be appreciated, especially if it generalizes to "continuous metric spaces".  I already know that counterexamples exist by this proof which seems clumsy (I wrote it myself) so if you know a better one, that is also welcome:

$C$ is uncountable because it contains all the point masses for points in $[0, \infty)$.  Since $[0, \infty)$ is a Polish topological space, then by work done in Kechris' book, $P([0, \infty))$ is a Polish topological space.  But $P([0, \infty))$ is uncountable because it contains all the pointmasses on that interval regarded as measures on that interval.  So that means that it's Borel isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ by the Borel isomorphism theorem.  Actually, the natural correspondence between $C$ and $P([0, \infty))$ is a homeomorphism in this case since any continuous function on the half interval can be extended continuously.  This Borel isomorphism, now of $C$ with $\mathbb{R}$ gives us a correspondence of distributions on these spaces, with countable sums of point masses corresponding.  Since there are other types of measures on the line, then there are some on $C$ as well.

Comment: Let $U(a,b)$ represent the uniform probability measure on $[a,b]$. How about the set $\{U(0,\lambda): \lambda\in[1,2]\}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\{U(0,\lambda): \lambda\in[x,y]\}) = y-x$ for all $x,y\in[1,2],x<y$? I don't know what $\sigma$-algebra you're using, but perhaps you can make this example make sense?

Comment: Draw $(M,V)$ randomly from the distribution on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R_+$ of your choice and consider the normal distribution $\mu$ with mean $M$ and variance $V$, then $\nu:B\mapsto\mu(B)+\mu(-B)$ for every Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb R_+$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comments, one more example: for $x\in [0,1]$ let $\mu_x$ be the uniform distribution on $[x,x+1]$. Push forward the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ by the map $x\mapsto \mu_x$. Being injective, this map pushes the Lebesgue measure to a non-atomic measure.